# java. do not accept 0 as first input in a text field

Tags: java

I'm using Java and this part of my code is for entering age in a text field that only accepts numbers, back spaces and delete. How can I also tell the code to avoid accepting 0 if its the first character ?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
private void tfAgeKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               

    char c = evt.getKeyChar();

    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: validate your form... if(yourString.charAt(0)=='0') DONT LET EM !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just need to check if your entered character isn't equal to `0` in your condition using `c == '0'` **when the current input is empty**:

```
if((this.currentInput.isEmpty() && (!Character.isDigit(c) || c == '0')) || !(Character.isDigit(c)) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
    evt.consume();
}
```

Comment: You're nearly there, but your condition allows any garbage character to be entered as the first character. All characters must be digits. In other words, the input string is a number but must not start with 0.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Well pointed out, thank you, I edited the answer.

Comment: The second and subsequent characters must also be digits.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes of course, and the first condition will be only `true` if ther's no charcters entered, so for more than one character, it will be passed :)

Comment: The "`|| !(Character.isDigit(c))`" in your condition will cause problems. For example, it will allow you to input "a" as the first character.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Oh my bad, I miswrote the condition, it should be `(this.currentInput.isEmpty() && (!Character.isDigit(c) || c == '0'))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tfAgeKeyTyped(final java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               

    final char c = evt.getKeyChar();

    // You need access to the current input to known if you are on the 
    // first character or not. 
    // Here I assume it exists as a private member variable. 
    final boolean isFirstChar = this.currentInput.isEmpty();

    final boolean isValidEvent = (Character.isDigit(c) && !(isFirstChar && c == '0')) || 
        (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || 
        (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);

    if (isValidEvent) {
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```